# multidimensional array remove item from child array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have a problem with my multidimensional array. I want to remove some items from child array by $id value.

here is my multidimensional example array and selectedIds:

```
$myArray = [
    ['id' => '2', 
    'name' => 'Punk'
    ],[
    'id' => '5', 
    'name' => 'Rock', 
    'children' => [
        '30' => ['id' => '30', 
                'name' => 'Hard Rock', 
                'parentId' => '5'
                ], 
        '40' => ['id' => '40', 
                'name' => 'Soft Rock', 
                'parentId' => '5'
                ],  
        '50' => ['id' => '50', 
                'name' => 'Glam Rock', 
                'parentId' => '5'
                ]
        ]
    ]
];

$selectedIds = [2,5,30];
```

and i want to remove from array those items which are not in selectedIds array.

so i want to have output:

```
$outputArray = [
    [
    'id' => '2', 
    'name' => 'Punk'
    ],[
    'id' => '5', 
    'name' => 'Rock', 
    'children' => [
            '30' => ['id' => '30', 
                    'name' => 'Hard Rock', 
                    'parentId' => '5']
                ]
    ]
];
```

i try to make it with foreach and array_key_exist but its not correct:

```
foreach ($myArray as $key=>$value) {
    if (array_key_exists('children', $value)) {
        foreach ($selectedIds as $id) {
            if (isset($value['children'][$id])) {
                $outputArray[] = $value['children'][$id];
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($outputArray);
```

this outpus is only item with id 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write `else part` into your code if array has no `children key`

```
else{
    foreach ($selectedIds as $id) {
        if ($value['id'] == $id) {
            $outputArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Final code**

```
<?PHP
$myArray = [
    [
        'id' => '2', 
        'name' => 'Punk'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '5', 
        'name' => 'Rock', 
        'children' => [
            '30' => ['id' => '30', 
                    'name' => 'Hard Rock', 
                    'parentId' => '5'
                    ], 
            '40' => ['id' => '40', 
                    'name' => 'Soft Rock', 
                    'parentId' => '5'
                    ],  
            '50' => ['id' => '50', 
                    'name' => 'Glam Rock', 
                    'parentId' => '5'
                    ]
            ]
        ]
];

$selectedIds = [2,5,30];

foreach ($myArray as $key=>$value) {
    if (array_key_exists('children', $value)) {
        foreach ($selectedIds as $id) {
            if (isset($value['children'][$id])) {
                $outputArray[$key]['id'] = $value['id'];
                $outputArray[$key]['name'] = $value['name'];
                $outputArray[$key]['children'][$id] = $value['children'][$id];
            }
        }
    }else{
        foreach ($selectedIds as $id) {
            if ($value['id'] == $id) {
                $outputArray[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($outputArray);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Punk
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Rock
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [30] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 30
                            [name] => Hard Rock
                            [parentId] => 5
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: but i want to maintain structure. I need to have 2,5,30 so id = 5, name = Rock children = [id = 30, name = Hard Rock, ParentId = 5] is missing

Comment: now check with output, i have updated my anwser

Comment: if you have got the correct output? so please also give upvote so any other also get help from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i make other code more simple. That´s here:

just change a bit the foreach content:

```
foreach ($myArray as $key=>&$value) {
    if (array_key_exists('children', $value)) {
        $value['children'] = array_intersect_key($value['children'], array_flip($selectedIds));
    }
}
```

Use `array_flip`for transform keys on values and `array_intersect_key`for get only they id´s that exist in 2 arrays.

here you can see a [live demo](https://paiza.io/projects/2oIyuNnKYLGQrk0dW4sokA)

NOTE: take care that i´m passing the value by referer **&$value** in the foreach for modify the original array, if you dont want this just duplicate the original array and modify the second.